# xml file encryption with Python

Tags: python, encryption

i am making a mail client and i have made an option in which user can save his/her profile 
and i saving all details in an xml file using **SXML** lib in **python** . now i want that file to be encrypted otherwise any one can see the details...How do i Do dat?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using a [Recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577090-file-encryption-using-stream-cipher/) from Active state for some time, you can find stronger algorithms but if you just need to keep away the curious it will be ok :)

If you really need a higher degree of confidence you can try [pyDES](http://twhiteman.netfirms.com/des.html) and use a TripleDES for the encryptation.

[TripleDES](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way:

Accept the password from the user and then store it use `base64`.

```
>>> import base64
>>> print base64.b64encode("password")
cGFzc3dvcmQ=
>>> print base64.b64decode("cGFzc3dvcmQ=")
password
```

So encode the `password` and save it in the XML file and then when you want to read from it, decode it.

[DOCS](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html)

PS: I am not saying this is highly secure, but still this will suffice for a casual glance at the file. Again if you need it to be really secure (is that even possible?), then you should find something else. This solution is more about being obscure.